# Progress DB File to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, openedge

Hi I have a progress database .db file. Is there a way to import it to mssql?

Thinks I've tried:

- Importing to an ODBC - not sure what i'm doing here.
- Reading the database to proenv and export it to mssql but what can i only do is import the table schema only due to license problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540369/extract-from-progress-database-to-sql-server

Comment: @MitchWheat I sure do. Always hit a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the data (and possibly the schema) from the db-file. You could start with downloading the free edition to see if you can connect to the database doing that. Another way would be to contact Progress and requesting an time limited evaluation version to connect.

A good source for help is the Knowledge Base ([knowledgebase.progress.com](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/)). Search it on specific issues like dumping data and schema.